# Script with which I can change the font dynamically when the page is live using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want a JavaScript with which I can change the font dynamically when the page is live (Arial to Times). But when I click Arial or Times, the page should not get refreshed. Can anyone please help me in this? Or can anyone please provide a script for this?

Comment: you should be looking at javascript for this, not php

Comment: ya javascript.. can u pls provide a script...

Comment: -1 Try first, then ask.  If you don't know what to try, research.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know if it's good for Kenny to make his job (= a simple student's project) or just to say "go look on the net and make it yourself". We won't do your project for you man ! That's why I voted "+1" to the Justin Johnson comment because he's one of the few who have guessed it's a student question who thinks "Ok I'm too lazy to do it someone will do it for me thus I can party all night !". By the way: I do hate SMS-style, this just shows you don't respect the other ones who'll read your question.

Comment: k olivier if ur nt interested to reply for ma question well nd good.. i know to respect others k.. no need to take it from u..

Comment: You may have answered "Okay Olivier if **you** **are** **not** interested to reply ... and so on: I mean: I'm French I'm trying my best to write proper English, just to show I'm trying to respect the other people who will read my post. This is a kind of "respecting the other ones". I hope my suggestion about making an effort this way will be okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do this with javascript, not php.
Use javascript to change the style of the text dynamically. Php is run on the server, and is therefor not in the picture for your no-reload scenario.

*Example*

Here is the first [simple example](http://ilovethecode.com/Javascript/Javascript-Tutorials/Javascript_Change_Fonts.shtml) google returned (e.g. search "javascript change text font" for more examples):

```
<html>
<body>
<div id=hey>
    <a onMouseover="document.getElementById('hey').style.fontFamily='courier'"> Make me COURIER!</a> ----
    <a onMouseover="document.getElementById('hey').style.fontFamily='verdana'"> Make me VERDANA!!!</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use PHP and don't want the entire page to reload, you would need some form of AJAX implmentation.

However...your problem can be solved more easily with Javascript and I would recommend using that instead. The jQuery library allows you to change CSS styles with minimal code. There are a few code examples on changing style attributes on the jQuery website.

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/css#namevalue

It should get you started on applying similar code to change the font type of a paragraph. Download Jquery for your site and you'll be ready to go.